# How do I know if the fonts in a PDF file are embedded or not?

Tags: windows, pdf, fonts, embedded

How can I understand that the fonts in a PDF file are embedded or not?

Comment: You may check this excellent answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/21400047/520567

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In Adobe Reader, go to File -> Properties, then click on the Fonts tab.  Embedded fonts will have either (Embedded) or (Embedded Subset) after the font name.

In Foxit Reader, the process is pretty similar.  Go to File -> Properties, then click on the Fonts tab.  Foxit doesn't say if it's a subset or not, but it does show (Embedded) after the font name if the font is embedded.

However, Foxit doesn't seem to identify all the embedded fonts -- looking at the Foxit manual (in PDF), it identifies a little over half of the embedded fonts as being embedded, but misses the rest.  This is most likely a bug in Foxit Reader (version 3.2.1).

Comment: Thanks for making it clear for Foxit. I guess I'll have to install Adobe Reader.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the document properties inside the document (both Adobe Reader and FoxIt Reader include a property page which lists all fonts uses in the document and their status).

Comment: I looked at it (on Foxit reader) but couldn't see any info about embedding. The fonts are listed together with their type (arial truetype etc.), encoding (ansi), actual font, actual font type. Other tabs in document properties don't tell about it either.

Comment: I don't know about Foxit reader but in Adobe Reader, Richard's method works. If the font is embedded you'll see something like "Arial (Embedded subset)" or just the name of the font and its properties if  it's not embedded.

Comment: @Mehper, @pelms: just checked with Foxit, it does show "(Embedded)" for some fonts on at least one document here.