# how to extract text from pdf with embedded subset fonts

Tags: pdf, embedded-fonts, xpdf

**Pdftotext** of **xpdf** is working fine for normal embedded fonts file , but fails where embedded subsets fonts are there . Is there any workaround for this issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is probably that the characters which are rendered using the subset font have a custom encoding - the numeric representation of the characters does not correspond to ASCII, Latin-1 or any other common encoding.

See

- [PDF Font encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12704781/477035)
- [Unsearchable, uncopiable PDF document](https://superuser.com/q/164907/52492)
- [How do I know if the fonts in a PDF file are embedded or not?](https://superuser.com/q/140613/52492)

This means there isn't an easy workaround.

Answer (score 2):

In this situation, I have printed the PDFs using the Adobe PDF printer via a high resolution (1200 dpi+), high quality image(up any settings you can). Then, I OCR the image PDF leaving me with a searchable and workable PDF.

When I have many PDFs to do over thousands of pages, I have opened multiple PDF windows at once to do this simultaneously using multiple cores for multiple PDFs.  It is a PITA, but it works.

Hopefully your files are small!  I've done this to upwards of 10,000 pages once (building code books).  Not fun.

Comment: Thanks for the answer . But how come the pdf viewer is able to correctly interpret it ?

Comment: Probably because the encoding is embedded in the PDF, not the program.